# how to search between two colomns data in mysql database using java.below hear eg

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

this is my query

```
select * from TABLE where date='"+DATE.getText()+"' And proofreader='"+NAME.getSelectedItem()+"'
```

**Example:**

```
DATE    NAME      MATHS  SCIENCE    ENGLISH 
12/21   amila     ok       no         ok
12/21   namal     ok       ok         ok
12/21   amila     no       ok         no
12/21   janitha   no       no         ok
12/21   janitha   ok       no         no
12/21   janitha   no       ok         no
12/22   amila     ok       ok         ok
```

I need search together this table: both `DATE` and `NAME` searching. Like this:

```
12/21 janitha result :

  no    no    ok
  ok    no    no
  no    ok    no
```

Comment: And what you have tried?

Comment: i tried search using  two columns data

Comment: Show us some code. We can't simply mind map.

Comment: for example is, a one day ,a one persons doing lots of thing. i create a simple diary using java + sql with netbeans. then i need search on under my diary records using day and person name then can get lots of data about that day. this diary use more peoples. then when date and name searching  need get that details

Comment: sir Nambri  can you understand my poor english :D

Comment: Well, the issue here is, I was asking for query you have written so far, based on that we can suggest solution. I don't want to answer based on theory. If you have done any query, please update your question with the query.

Comment: hmmm no sir i havent quary.please can you guide me lern sarch quary for two columns.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264565(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: thnks sir.! but this using for between M and A . but i want quary for two columns
SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, HireDate, City FROM Employees
WHERE (FirstName NOT LIKE 'M%') AND (FirstName NOT LIKE 'A%')

Comment: thanks sir i understand tahts can set after the where in quary, columns1 and columns 2.  :D

Comment: this is my code sir! 
 select * from TABLE where date='"+DATE.getText()+"' And proofreader='"+NAME.getSelectedItem()+"'
i need with tgeter aftr runing need search result this both clmns